# How to prove that $E[U_1U_2 \mid |U_1-U_2|<a]$ is the sum of two double integrals?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that $U_1, U_2 \sim Unif(0,1)$ are iid random variables. I am trying to find:

$$
E[U_1U_2 \mid |U_1-U_2|<a]
$$

for $a<\frac{1}{2}$.

It appears that the answer is:

$$
\int_{u_1 = 0}^1 \int_{u_2 = u_1}^{u_1 + a} u_1 u_2 
\text{d} u_2 \text{d} u_1
+
    \int_{u_2 = 0}^1 \int_{u_1 = u_2}^{u_2 + a} u_1 u_2 
\text{d} u_1 \text{d} u_2
$$

However, I have no idea how the conditional expectation was turned into two integrals with the bounds. Can anyone walk me through how exactly this result formally came about? Thanks.

Comment: At the most, the sum of these two integrals might be $$E(U_1U_2;|U_1-U_2|<a)$$ You are right to point out that, to compute $$E(U_1U_2\mid |U_1-U_2|<a)$$ one would have to divide this by $$P(|U_1-U_2|<a)$$ Additionally, the limits of the integrals in your post are wrong, since each upper limit of an inner integral $$u_k+a$$ should read $$\min\{u_k+a,1\}$$ What is the source for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That integral does not look correct, for example in the first term when $u_1=1$ you will integrate $u_2$ from $1$ to $1+a$ which is outside the joint region of $U_1$ and $U_2$.

The region where $|U_1-U_2|<a$ is the region in the unit square which is bounded above by  $U_2 = U_1+a$ and below by $U_2 = U_1-a$.

To integrate this you would need the sum of three double integrals $$ \int_{u_1=0}^{a}\int_{u_2=0}^{u_1+a} u_1u_2du_2du_1 + \int_{u_1=a}^{1-a}\int_{u_2=u_1-a}^{u_1+a} u_1u_2du_2du_1 + \int_{u_1=1-a}^{1}\int_{u_2=u_1-a}^{1} u_1u_2du_2du_1 $$